# Asp .Net Core Razor 500 Http Error when going to Login page

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm starting with razor pages and I created a login page and used ldap to authenticate and logged in. Still don't have logout option. Here's the thing, I want the Login to be default page so I deleted every single default page from razor template but the error leaving the Login only

```
Pages 
  Account Folder 
  Login page
```

Problem is after having logged in, now whenever i try to access login page it gives me this error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure Common causes
>   of this issue: The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found. The in process request
>   handler, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, was not referenced in the
>   application. ANCM could not find dotnet. Troubleshooting steps: Check
>   the system event log for error messages Enable logging the application
>   process' stdout messages Attach a debugger to the application process
>   and inspect For more information visit:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2028526

I couldn't find anything about this error happening only on one page, just about IIS.

This only happens on login page, i can access other pages normally...

Here is the code on my login page

```
@page
@model GestaoRequisicoes.Pages.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h1>Login</h1>

<p>Autentique-se para iniciar sessão:</p>
<form method="post">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Username</label>
                    <input asp-for="loginData.Username" value="username" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input asp-for="loginData.Password" value="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input id="txtRememberMe" asp-for="loginData.RememberMe" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="txtRememberMe">Remember me</label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
```

and cs file

```
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public LoginData loginData { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {            

    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {                             
            string dominio = "10.35.14.240/OU=Users,OU=PLG,OU=PT,OU=EMEA,DC=sd6,DC=glb,DC=corp,DC=local";
            string adPath = "LDAP://" + dominio;

            LDAPAutenticador aut = new LDAPAutenticador(adPath);
            var isValid = aut.autenticado(dominio, loginData.Username, loginData.Password);

            if (!isValid)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "username or password is invalid");
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, ClaimTypes.Name, ClaimTypes.Role);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, loginData.Username));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginData.Username));
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = loginData.RememberMe });
                return RedirectToPage("Account/Index");
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "username or password is blank");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    public class LoginData
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(8)]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the startup file

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddCookie(options => { options.LoginPath = "/Login"; });

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options => 
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");

        }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It has been awhile but if anyone notices some error like this just check windows event viewer and it tells you the error message. The message was something about Connection Pool Timeout exception with Entity Framework. I assume Entity Framework just failed to connect to SQL Server until I refreshed databases on SQL Server explorer, probably because I'm using localdb\mssqlserver instance for testing but it's still an odd behaviour and only happens when running your project first time everyday